# Prevent Docker from rebuilding certain parts of Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I don't know exactly how caching in Docker works, so how can I modify this section in my Dockerfile in a way that Docker don't rebuild it each time ?

```
# INSTALL OPENCV 3.1
WORKDIR /root
RUN wget https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/archive/3.1.0.zip -O opencv_contrib-3.1.0.zip -nv && \
  unzip opencv_contrib-3.1.0.zip && \
  rm -f /root/opencv_contrib-3.1.0.zip && \
  wget https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.1.0.zip -O opencv-3.1.0.zip -nv && \
  unzip opencv-3.1.0.zip && \
  rm -f /root/opencv-3.1.0.zip

RUN export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

WORKDIR /root/opencv-3.1.0

RUN mkdir build && cd build && \
  cmake -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=3.2 \
    -D CUDA_ARCH_PTX=3.2 \
    -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D WITH_TBB=ON \
    -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \
    -D WITH_V4L=ON \
    -D BUILD_TIFF=ON \
    -D WITH_QT=ON \
 #   -D USE_GStreamer=ON \
    -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
    -D WITH_IPP=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/root/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules \
    -D BUILD_opencv_legacy=OFF .. && \
  make -j8 && \
  make install && \
  echo "/usr/local/lib" | sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf && \
  ldconfig && \
  cp /root/opencv-3.1.0/build/lib/cv2.so /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so

RUN rm -rf /root/opencv-3.1.0 /root/opencv_contrib-3.1.0 # cleanup
```

Comment: When building docker container it checks differences between already build image and new one. That being said, you should write your docker file in a way that files which will not change would get cached first . Eg get all dependencies, and at the end add your files with code which I assume will change quite often

Comment: This section of my Dockerfile has never changed, and I've fixed the version of OpenCV that will be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are depending on $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, a non-deterministic build time variable. Try escaping the dollar sign: \$LD_LIBRARY_PATH